# string variable and parameter evaluation

Tags: javascript

```
function addRow(){
    var row=`<input name="car[].name">
    <input type='text' name='car[].defaultPrice'></td>
    `;
    $("#carsTable tbody").append(row);  
}
```

How to pass a concatenate value passed to this function?

if I pass `i=0`

I would like to get

```
var row=`<input name="car[0].name"><input type='text' name='car[0].defaultPrice'></td>`;
```

Comment: Your function doesn't accept any arguments. Did you mean to write `function addRow(i)`?

Comment: Your `row` is a string. So you just have to concat string values.

Comment: Also, you might want to check if 'i' is not greater then 'car' array length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var row=`<input name="car[${i}].name">
<input type='text' name='car[${i}].defaultPrice'></td>
`;
```

assuming you are using ES6, you can use `${i}` in order to use the values of variables between the backticks.

Answer (score 3):

Making use of string interpolation:

```
function addRow(i) {
    var row=`
        <td>
            <input name="car[${i}].name">
            <input type='text' name='car[${i}].defaultPrice'>
        </td>`;
    $("#carsTable tbody").append(row);  
}
```

Regular string:

```
function addRow(i) {
    var row="<td>" +
                "<input name='car[" + i + "].name'>" +
                "<input type='text' name='car[" + i + "].defaultPrice'>" +
            "</td>";
    $("#carsTable tbody").append(row);  
}
```

Though, if you want the name property to evaluate to the actual content of `car[i].defaultPrice` and `name`, you will need to do the following:

```
var car = [
    { name: 'Test', defaultPrice: 20000 },
    { name: 'Test2', defaultPrice: 25000 }
];

function addRow(i) {
    var row=`
        <td>
            <input name="${car[i].name}">
            <input type='text' name='${car[i].defaultPrice}'>
        </td>`;
    $("#carsTable tbody").append(row);  
}
```

Then call the function:

```
addRow(0);
addRow(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the desired number as an argument to the function:

```
function addRows(number) {

    var row = '' +
        '<td>' +
            '<input name="car[' + number + '].name">' +
            '<input type='text' name="car[' + number + '].defaultPrice">' +
        '</td>';

    $("#carsTable tbody").append(row);

}
```